# Unable to add height on child when I add position relative on parent

Tags: html, css, height

I want to add a `height` to child `div` but when I add `position: relative` to parent then it doesn't work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box">
  <div class="child-box">
    <h4>child box</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: relative to what? If you have no further ancestors then it will be relative to body, whose height is set by the height of its contents in this case which is the padding. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your root element and body to take up 100% of the height.

**Explanation:**
Your parent box had a height of 100%, that is the full height of its parent - the body. You hadn't set a height on the body, and its initial height is auto. Therefore your height was auto, only taking up the space needed to fit the content and padding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box">
  <div class="child-box">
    <h4>child box</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an improved solution with less code:

Width 100% is default for block elements, inset can be used for the child div instead of height and top/left, top and left have no effect on relative positioned elements so remove them from the parent.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.child-box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box">
  <div class="child-box">
    <h4>child box</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```